# I want to execute a Code which is inside text file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a Code which passes dates arguments to a visual basic code which is inside excel file.Code inside the Date.txt file is pasted below:

```
`Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`
'With objExcel'
'.Workbooks.Open "C:\emailfetch\FetchEmails.xlsm"'
'.Visible = True'
'.Run "FolderTraverse",cLng(DateSerial(2014,3,1)),cLng(DateSerial(2014,3,4))'
'.ActiveWorkbook.Close True'
'.Quit'
'End With'
```

I need to execute the above code from execute.bat file. Execute.bat file consists 2 other files .Codes need to executed

In Steps

- 1.Date.txt
- 2.makezip.vbs
- 3.mailsend.cmd.

Can anybody helps how to execute the code which is inside Date.txt with the help of batch file execute.bat

Comment: Shouldn't dates.txt be dates.vbs since it's vbscript code? You can try cscript //nologo dates.txt to run it from the batch file. If that doesn't work, rename dates.txt to dates.vbs and try it that way.

Comment: Hi Matt,Initially the date.txt was in vbs and it was working preety fine,but I was asked to get the date parameters from a text file instead of vbs .So that's why I changed date.vbs to date.txt.I am looking for workaround such that dates can be entered from a text file

Comment: I executed the execute.bat with the following content: cscript //nologo date.txt
Makezip.vbs
mailsend.cmd.

Comment: I got following error:Input error:There is no script engine for file extension ".txt"

Answer (score 1):

You can do this two ways. Both require you to make 2 files.

---

- 1: Using a windows scripting host framework xml wrapper. Which allows you to execute windows scripts regardless of language via command prompt.

---

**scriptrollout.wsf**

```
<job>
<script language="VBScript" src="data.txt"/>
<script language="VBScript" src="makezip.vbs"/>
</job>
```

**batchfile.bat**

```
cscript.exe  scriptrollout.wsf
mailsend.cmd
```

---

- 2: Using the ExecuteGlobal Command

---

**ExecGlob.vbs**

```
Function Include(vbs)
    Dim fso, f, s : Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(vbs) : s = f.ReadAll()
    f.Close : ExecuteGlobal s
End Function

Include "Date.txt"
Include "makezip.vbs
```

**batchfile.bat**

```
cscript.exe  ExecGlob.wsf
mailsend.cmd
```

---